# Can't use cURL library due to /clr:safe in C++

Tags: c++, forms, curl, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to use the curl library in my c++ project which uses windows forms. To compile the forms project I need to use /clr:safe otherwise I get a compile error:

"Error  LNK1309 ijw/native module detected; invalid with switch /CLRIMAGETYPE:SAFE"

However whenever I try to include curl.h I get 2000+ errors. Is there some work around for this?

Comment: "I get 2000+ errors" - Yet you didn't think to show us even *one* of them. Why not? Do you think we are mind readers? How can we comment on something we cannot see?

Comment: Looks like you're targeting .NET. Can't you use the .NET library's own HTTP client, e. g.`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`? Capability-wise, it's on par with CURL. Also, debugging mixed native/managed C++ is a terrible chores.